# basic question on normed algebra

Tags: operator-algebras

Prove the multiplication map $m:A\times A\rightarrow A$, sending $(x,y)\rightarrow x*y$ is jointly continuous in a normed algebra.
i can't understand what's jointly cont.? this is a problem from evan's monumental book on quantum symmetries and operator algebra

Comment: By $A*A$ do you mean $A\times A$ or some other product?

Comment: yes i mean that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been very nice answers using product topology. But since you are talking about *normed* algebras, I guess there is an easier answer.

The product $\cdot:A\times A\to A$ is jointly continuous if there is $C<+\infty$ such that \begin{equation}
\|a\cdot b\|\le C\|a\|\|b\|
\end{equation}  for all $a,b\in A$.

This is to be distinguished from *separately* continuous, which says for each $a\in A$, there is $C_a<+\infty$ such that \begin{equation}
\|a\cdot b\|\le C_a\|b\|,
\end{equation} and \begin{equation}
\|b\cdot a\|\le C_a\|b\|
\end{equation} for all $b\in A$.

Note that the difference is that this constant $C_a$ depends on $a$. But if your are talking about Banach algebra then these two are the same as a consequence of Banach-Stenhauss.

Also as far as I know this is a standard terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Jointly continuous appears to mean continuous on the product topology. For example, the first (non-PDF) page that came up when I Googled the term was http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Jointly_continuous_map

The fact that the first Google result was a PDF suggests that it is not a very standard term...

Comment: In my experience, jointly continuous in a Banach space refers to a biliniear form $B$ where if $a_n,b_n$ each go to zero, then $B(a_n,b_n)$ does as well. Banach spaces are normed algebras.

Comment: I agree that it means continuous on the product topology, and I think it is fairly standard.  Roughly it means that if $(a,b)$ is close to $(c,d)$ then $ab$ is close to $cd$, which can be made precise using the inequality $\|ab-cd\|=\|ab-cb+cb-cd\|\leq\|a-c\|\|b\|+\|c\|\|b-d\|$.